# How can I evaluate a string into an object in Python?

Tags: python, django, types

I am working on creating a Django forums project and I have a "settings" app which access the database for a table called settings.

The table is setup with a `verbose_name`, `name`, and `value` columns. The first is simply a name to be displayed to admins, the second is the name that the setting is accessed by (and is the primary key on the table.)

Now, I have some settings which are boolean, some which are integers, and some of which are string. However, `value` is a TEXT type in the Database so Django is returning it as a string. Right now I have this implementation to convert booleans into the Python boolean type:

```
class SettingsMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.settings = {}
        settings = Setting.objects.all()

        for setting in settings:
            if setting.value == ("True" or "1"):
                setting.value = True
            if setting.value == ("False" or "0"):
                setting.value = False

            request.settings[setting.name] = setting.value

        return None
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to go about this?
2. How can I determine whether the string contains an integer? I know that I can convert it to an integer with `int()` if it is valid, but how can I tell whether or not it is valid?

Obviously, regarding question number two, I would remove the or "1" and or "0" bits of the current evaluation.

Comment: You could also serialize your data using something like JSON or pickle and then reload it with that

Comment: @JeffS I considered using JSON to serialize and deserialize it, however I realized that I would be inserting rows that looked like {"value": true} and {"value": "Please verify your email!"} and it was really a waste of space as JSON would be looping through the same way I would, albeit with (probably) more overhead.

Comment: If you're worried about the overhead, and can take on the security risk, pickle might be a good choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) might be useful to you.

```
>>> import  ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("1")
1
>>> ast.literal_eval("0")
0
>>> ast.literal_eval("True")
True
>>> ast.literal_eval("False")
False
>>> ast.literal_eval("'foobar'")
'foobar'
>>> ast.literal_eval("1.2")
1.2
>>> ast.literal_eval("1.2e3")
1200.0
>>> ast.literal_eval("1,2")
(1, 2)
>>> ast.literal_eval("[1,2]")
[1, 2]
>>> ast.literal_eval("[1,2,(1,2)]")
[1, 2, (1, 2)]
>>> ast.literal_eval("1f")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    1f
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: This looks good. I'm going to leave this open for a little bit and if there aren't any other better answers I'll mark this as best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict it to 0,1,True,False, I'd do

```
boolmapping = {'0':False, 'False': False, '1':True, 'True':True}
...
setting = boolmapping.get(setting, setting)
```

However, this may mistakenly convert an integer that happens to be 1 to True, when really 1 was meant, so you may better map '1' to `1`, not `True`.

To convert a string to an int if it is one, do

```
try:
    setting = int(setting)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would work, but are there any advantages to this over ast.literal_eval()?

Comment: I can't think of any place in python where you couldn't use `True` instead of `1` -- except with a check using the `is` operator I suppose...

Comment: @John -- This approach is probably faster than the `literal_eval` at the cost of a lot of flexibility (which is sometimes preferable)

Comment: To be clear, I meant that at times, a less flexible solution is desirable.

Comment: @mgilson: The most canonical case where True won't work in place of 1 is string conversion. If you use the value to fill out a field in a text file, the text file may become incorrect if you put True where 1 is required.

Comment: @John: in your specific case, ast.literal_eval may misinterpret some string. E.g. if you have the string "[7]", then literal_eval will take it as a list. As you said that your settings may only contain bool, int, and str, getting a list would be an unexpected value, possibly causing a TypeError later. OTOH, if you declare that configuration values may be arbitrary Python expressions, then literal_eval is exactly right.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point you've got there, thank you. I did switch to ast.literal_eval, but there are places where users will be able to enter any text, and if it is a number or something resembling a list there would be issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
if setting.value in ["true", "True", 1, "1"]:
    setting.value = True
```

Comment: I'm looking to add support for integers as well, as per question number two.